# How to insert bzr revision number to each revision controlled file as a comment during commit and/or push

Tags: version-control, bazaar, bzr-svn

We use bzr as the version control system at work and we've come to realize that in a certain project, it would be quite handy if each of the revision controlled files had the revision number as a comment on the first line of each file.

In a nutshell I want to add **# BZR REV: xxx** to each python file during commit.

A quick bash script would achieve this but as I understand this should be standard practice in other version control systems like SVN, so I'm hoping for a builtin way to achieve what I need. Also it would save me the trouble of writing that bash script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [bazaar keywords plugin](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/keywords-plugin.html).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. Looks like just what we need.